# get file name boto3 python

Tags: amazon-s3, flask, boto3

I'm a new in flask and boto3 and want create a simple upload form to s3 amazon and i need to save file on s3 with the existing filename and return link to this file.

Two issues:

1) In the example below file always uploads with a name 'test'. If upload file name will be 'my file.pdf' i need to upload file to s3 with the same name ('file.pdf'). 
I believe it can be done with request but i do not know how exactly. How it can be done?

2) How to return link to the file that i just have uploaded? (I have no idea)

below is my code

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return '''
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload">
     <input type="file" name="file" multiple>
     <input type="submit">
    </form>
    '''

@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def upload():
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    s3.Bucket('dimkzn').put_object(='test', Body=request.files['file'])
    return 'file save! to S3'
```

if **name**=='**main**':
    app.run(debug=True) code here

Answer (score 1):

In your upload function you are missing the **Key** parameter names where you have `="test"` which is why every file is being saved as test. You can pass through the filename from the file object within `request.files`

```
@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def upload():
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    s3.Bucket('dimkzn').put_object(Key=request.files['file'].filename, Body=request.files['file'])
    return 'file save! to S3'
```

The URL path will then be `https://s3-<region>.amazonaws.com/dimkzn/<filename>`

If you wish to upload the file into a subfolder, folders don't actually exist within S3 but you can create folder structures by changing the key of the file. E.G

```
@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def upload():
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    s3.Bucket('dimkzn').put_object(Key=f"media/example/{request.files['file'].filename}", Body=request.files['file'])
    return 'file save! to S3'
```

Will upload the file to:

`https://s3-<region>.amazonaws.com/dimkzn/media/example/<filename>`

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in the line:

```
s3.Bucket('dimkzn').put_object(='test', Body=request.files['file'])
```

You're missing an argument name before the ='test'.  I can't see from your code what request.files['file'] returns: is that the filename or the file content?

Correct syntax is

```
object = bucket.put_object(
    Body=b'bytes'|file,
    Key='filename')
```

...where Body is the content of the file, Key is the filename.

Once successful, you can construct the link yourself as follows:

```
https://s3-<region>.amazonaws.com/<bucketname>/<filename>
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Your Missing "Key", should be like this:
s3.Bucket('dimkzn').put_object(Key='test', Body=request.files['file']